# UIProgressView with custom progress image - iOS

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios7, uiprogressview

I would like to make a progress bar with progress image, but it doesn't work for me in any way. I've tried subclassing, storyboard's attributes inspector and other ways...
I would like to have progress image with gradient from left to right as this sample:
[Gradient for the progress image of progress bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K4Osj.png)
.
Does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 2):

You can set the `progressImage` property to set the image of the progress bar and the `trackImage` property for the empty track.

See the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIProgressView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIProgressView/progressImage).

Comment: It doesn't work for me. In storyboard looks good, but when I run it on the phone it doesn't work.